# MS Access Compare all fields in two tables

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a project that has a definite start and end date, with data that will be produced daily. Every day I will be receiving a dataset with all the data from the start of the project until the previous day (e.g. on Day 10 I will receive the data from days 1 to 9, on day 11 I will receive the data for days 1 to 10 etc.). Each row of data will have approx 15 fields and I need to be able to highlight if any retrospective changes have been made to any of the fields in each row of data.

Is there any way to do this?

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: This may give you a start http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=12731&sid=1a4229e343a154579571dda5d329dc52

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Say your table is called Table1 and has a primary key field named DAY, and 2 fields named field1, field2

Create a query:

```
 SELECT 
   A.field1 AS CurrentDay1
 , A.field2 AS CurrentDay2
 , B.Field1 AS PreviousDay1
 , B.Field2 AS PreviousDay2

 ' , iif(A.field1 <> B.field1, "DIFF","" ) AS DiffField1
 ' , iif(A.field2 <> B.field2, "DIFF","" ) AS DiffField2

 FROM Table1 AS A
 LEFT JOIN Table1 AS B
 ON ( A.DAY = B.DAY+1
```

This sets up a dataset that has the same columns for the current day and the previous day in the same row.

Base a form on this query.

In Access 2013 (and 2010 I think) you can set conditional formatting for a control based on CurrentDay1 to compare it value with another control PreviousDay1 and colour it accordingly (eg RED if different).

If you can't use conditional formatting you could  add additional column that dot he comparison as shown above.

let me know if you get it working...

I think the recordset and the form will still allow updating of data

Harvey

Comment: Hi Harvey, many thanks for your reply, but I am not sure I understand correctly. I will have two tables one with e.g. days 1 to 9 (let's call that Table A) and one with days 1 to 10 (Table B), and there will be multiple rows for each day. I need to be able to compare the data for days 1 to 9 in Table A with days 1 to 9 in Table B. Will your solution enable me to do this?

Comment: The code I wrote assumed that the primary key of the table is DAY, ie there is only one row of data per day.  The technique I coded will work, you will just need to join the tables using all the primary key fields.  The LEFT JOIN Table1 will need to take data from a different table if this is where the historic data you keep is stored.